# Unable to order by column in [R] using column heading assigned to variable

Tags: r, format

While ordering a dataframe by a specific column, I found this code to work:

```
sortState <- byState[order(na.omit(byState$"Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure")),]
```

but when I wanted to use a variable for sake of a more generalized function...

```
outcome <- "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"
sortState <- byState[order(na.omit(byState$outcome)),]
```

I received this error message:

> Error in order(na.omit(byState$outcome)) : argument 1 is not a vector
>   In addition: Warning message: In is.na(object) : is.na() applied to
>   non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a column name stored in a variable, you have to use `[[` or `[` instead of `$`:

```
byState[order(na.omit(byState[[outcome]])),]
```

Comment: Your answer resulted in < banging my head against the wall. Thank-you.